# Amazon transcoder convert gif to video

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, gif, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Q: Is it possible to convert a GIF to mp4 (or another video format) using elastic transcoder?

I have been looking at the documentation for Amazon Elastic Transcoder and it seems that they are treating .GIF files as video files.

I also know that they have the following preset: `1351620000001-100200`

So is there a way to convert it into a video instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic transcode does support animated GIFs as an input. You can see this confirmed in presentations they have given, although they seem not to provide a definitive list of supported input types in their documentation:

[image]

Assuming there is no problem with your input file then you should be able to specify the output format using the usual setting when you create a job.

One thing to check is that you are not doing any pre-processing on the GIF that converts it into one or more static images instead.